# Encoding in sprintf

Tags: c, encoding, printf

In the following code:

```
char test[50];
sprintf(test, "áéíóú");
```

is there a way to make *sprintf* interpret input characters as [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead of Unicode?
I mean, to make *test* contain 0xE1E9EDF3FA... instead of 0xC3A1C3A9C3ADC3B3C3BA...

Comment: No -- `sprintf` is just going to take whatever input it's given and copy it where you tell it to. It'll be up to the editor you're using to decide how to encode your accented characters -- you'll have to (at least) tell us what editor you're using for anybody to help with that.

Comment: Hmm...'fraid I can't help you with that one, but maybe somebody else has used it and will be able to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit this from inside your text editing program. This is a matter of the actual file that contains your source code.

To do that in most editors and IDEs there is a menu called ENCODING

EDIT: More specifically for Geany, which appears to be the software you are running go to:

*Document* >> *Set Encoding* >> *West European* >> *Western* (1252)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t utf2bin(unsigned char *dst, unsigned char *src, size_t dstlen);

int main (void)
{
unsigned char src[] = {0xC3, 0xA1, 0xC3, 0xA9, 0xC3, 0xAD, 0xC3, 0xB3, 0xC3, 0xBA, 0};
unsigned char dst[100];
size_t ret;

// ret = mbstowcs(dst,src, sizeof dst);
// ret = wcstombs(dst,src, sizeof dst);
ret = utf2bin(dst,src, sizeof dst);

printf("Src=%s.\n", src );
printf("Dst=%s.\n", dst );

return 0;
}

/* This code does not _interpret_ the utf8 code-points, only converts
** them to 8bit "characters" as used in the consumer-grade "operating systems" supplied by Microsoft.
**
** Warning: only two byte codes are handled here. Longer codes will produce erroneous output.
*/
size_t utf2bin(unsigned char *dst, unsigned char *src, size_t dstlen)
{
size_t pos;
for ( pos = 0; pos< dstlen; pos++ ) {
        if ((*src & 0xe0) == 0xc0) {
                dst[pos] = ((src[0] & 3) << 6) | (src[1] & 0x3f);
                src += 2;
                }
        else dst[pos] = *src++;
        }
if (pos && pos >= dstlen) pos--;
dst[pos] = 0;
return pos;
}
```